# Django QuerySet filter get queryset by id and other column(s)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get my user instance as well as my team members' user instances in the same query. Unfortunately, I am getting an empty query set. I am trying this :

```
users = User.objects.filter(invited_by=request.user.id, id = request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can use Q (for more details visit: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects).

To get both your and your team members instance you can write something like this :

`User.objects.filter(Q(invited_by=request.user.id)|Q(id = request.user.id))` . Here '|' operator is a OR operator. So you are saying give me instance where `invited_by =request.user.id` or `id = request.user.id` . That's why you are getting all your desire instances. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to run a `OR` operation using [**`Q`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) operator:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(invited_by=request.user.id)|Q(id = request.user.id))
```